# How to get class methods and variables to show up in a sidebar on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

My first CS class used Eclipse and I'm now in a CS class that uses VS Code. In Eclipse, there is a sidebar that shows all the variables, methods, constructors, etc that are used in a java class. The picture below shows that:

[image]

So far, for the most part, I really prefer VS Code over Eclipse. The sidebar in Eclipse is the only thing I wish I had in VS Code. It's not a necessity but I find it helpful. Is there a way to have something like that in VS Code?

Comment: have you looked in the OUTLINE View

Answer (score -1):

That sidebar in VS Code is the toggle OUTLINE at the bottom of the explorer tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Outline does not show variables.